# How to train a machine learning model for named entity recognition

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I cannot find any sources about the architectures of machine learning models to solve for NER problems. I vaguely knows it is a multiclass classification problem, but how can we format our input to feed into such multiclass classifier? I know the inputs must be annotated corpus, but how can we feed that chunk of pairs of (word, entity label) into the classifier? Or, how do you feature-engineer such corpus to feed into ML models? Or, in general, how can you train a custom NER from scratch with machine learning?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many libraries for training NER models.

- It's useful to know that this type of model/task is called [sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling) because it consists in predicting a label for every word, taking into account the other words close to the target word.
- The standard method is [Conditional Random Fields (CRF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field). There are various libraries, see for example [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/102672/64377).
- Traditionally a specific format called BIO (sometimes IOB) which stands for *Begin, Inside, Outside* is used as input (see a [very short example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/88051/64377)). The features can involve context words through custom *patterns* (see the documentation of the libraries for details).